# Modifying a system file with a root application

Tags: android, root

I'm new to android app development and have a question. I need to mount the system as rw, copy a file in  /system/etc (back up the file which I have done) then open the original file, (it's an xml file) parse through it and then add an element. I haven't written the part yet to parse the file but I'm just trying to see if I can write to the file.  I figured before I even write the xml parsing code I should see if I can at least write to the file but canWrite returns false. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

code in onCreate:

```
try {
        RunProcess= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

code in button click:

```
  try {
                DataOutputStream os;
                File file2 = new File("/system/etc/permissions/platform.xml");
                os = new DataOutputStream(RunProcess.getOutputStream());
                os.writeBytes("mount -o rw,remount /system\n");
                Log.d("MOUNT RW?", " RW WRITABLE? " + file2.canWrite());
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
                RunProcess.waitFor();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Backed up original file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
```

Comment: It seems to act like a **malware**.

Comment: No, it's not malware. I'm actually writing an application to add a file permission for the sd card. Similar to the KK SD card fix app(actually the same thing.. I'm doing it for learning purposes). I will make a back up of the file. Open platform.xml. parse it and add the permission I need for the sd card and then save it.  Not malware at all.